# Blazor : How can I Start Looping with Time ? Example - Generate one Question After 2 minute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have 10 Question with multiple answers. I want to generate new question in after every 2 minute. And also show the time to the User with each Question . How I can achieve this goal ?

I can't Display Time

```
<div>
    <h2> Time left : @*Here I want to show Time*@ </h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
    @if (id != 0)
    {
         @*This is Question Component & Here I pass the Question id *@
        <QuestionCard Id="@id.ToString()"></QuestionCard>
    }
    else
    {
        <MatH1>Loading . . . . .</MatH1>
    }
</div>


@code {


    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    private int id { get; set; } = 0;
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Start());

    }
    void Start()
    {
        //aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        id = 2;  //I Just pass manually Question id
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        aTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

I am totally new on Blazor. If have any mistake please forgive.

Comment: Can you please provide some code that you are having issues with?

Comment: @KieranDevlin Now I add my code with the Question & Thanks

Comment: You didn't add OnTimedEvent() and you didn't say what dit (not) happen. So: what is the problem?

Comment: Tip: you will never want or need Task.Run() in Blazor (or Asp.Net)

Comment: @HenkHolterman Not currently but when mono threading support is added, you will want to use it.

Comment: @KieranDevlin - the Mono 'support' is already there but it's of little use until Wasm/JS get real threads. Seems a long way of. But yes, then you might want to Run some Tasks.

Comment: @HenkHolterman From what the Blazor team said, Wasm, or more specifically, browser implementation of Wasm, already have thread support. The rest of the work is on mono. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12172

Comment: @KieranDevlin - you are right, I missed that. Still no sign of it in BlazorWasm though.

Comment: Well the language already has a concept of Thread and Task, it's just down to the runtime to implement that and call the right WASM instructions so technically there isn't anything to do in Blazor, as soon as mono implements it, it should work out of the box (which is nice).

Answer (score 5):

I did this to show Time

```
<p> @TimeLeft </p>

@code{
    TimeSpan TimeLeft = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
    string displayText = "";

    bool show=false;

    void Start()
    {
        Task.Delay(1000);
        displayText = "Start Time";
        show = true;
        Timer();


    }

    async Task Timer()
    {
        while (TimeLeft > new TimeSpan())
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
            StateHasChanged();
        }


        await AfterTime();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    Task AfterTime()
    {
        displayText = "Time Expire";
        TimeLeft =  new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: You did not include how Start() is started - which is rather important.

Comment: You can (should) make it `Task Start()` and then await it in OnInitializedAsync()

Comment: @HenkHolterman Sorry, I didn't explain, "Start() " this called by ButtonClick!

Comment: That's good but make it a `async Task Start()` and then just `... @onclick="Start"`

Comment: and `await Timer();`